# Internship in this role

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I'm interested in applying for an internship on a specific role and I'm trying to figure out the correct for of the following phrases:

*there are some open roles **for?** "job title"*

*I want to apply for an internship **in/for/at/on?** this role*

Answer (score 0):

- **apply for** an accounting, banking, finance, sales, logistics, legal internship at [your company]
- **apply for** an internship **in** banking,finance, sales, logistics [at your firm]

1) - **apply for an internship position or internship as** a sales associate [in your company]
2) - **apply to be an accounting (sales etc.) intern** at your company

You can either use the position, in which case: apply for
**Or**
You can use apply to be an [business area] intern.

As seen here:

**Typical Internship Positions**

[BUNKER HILL COMMUNITY COLLEGE](https://www.bhcc.edu/learnandearn/internshippositions/)

And here:

WRITING AN **INTERNSHIP POSITION** DESCRIPTION
Writing a strong position description for your internship opportunity helps you attract the right candidates for the position and helps promote the name and reputation of your organization.

[CALTECH](http://career.caltech.edu/employers/internships/positiondescription)

Comment: internship is not a position

Comment: @Brad You are mistaken. internship position or position as an intern. Both are acceptable.

Comment: Well it is American.

Comment: Just checked M W seems to agree with Cambridge. P.S. if you are correct.  I am misled by the dictionary not mistaken,

Comment: You are mistaken in disagreeing with me. internship position where internship functions like an adjective can be used. The word position can, of course, be left out.

Answer (score -2):

I prefer to use "**as**" which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/as) states is:

> **as<sup>1</sup>**
>   PREPOSITION
>
> **1** Used to refer to the function or character that someone or something has.
>   *she got a job as a cook*.

So you could say

> I want to apply for an internship **as** *role*.

Comment: I want to apply "to serve" an internship as role.

Comment: @Brad I think your answer should speak for itself.

Answer (score -2):

**I want to apply for an internship in/for/at/on?**

---

I would like to apply for the position of a/an ...... intern .

example  I would like to apply for the position of  a car sales person intern.

if you really feel you must use the word internship rather than intern. Then you **would apply to "serve" an internship** in what ever.

> After he'd served his apprenticeship he set up his own business.
>   [CAMBRIDGE ENGLISH DICTIONARY](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/serve)

---

**Note** the job is INTERN the period of time is INTERNSHIP, you are applying to be an intern who will serve an internship. So the correct word is you are applying for the position of intern.

---

> **intern** noun [CAMBRIDGE ENGLISH DICTIONARY](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intern?q=INTERN) HR, WORKPLACE **a student**, or someone who has recently finished their studies, **who works for a company** or organisation **for a short time**, sometimes without being paid, in order **to get experience** of a particular type of work:
>
> **internship** noun [CAMBRIDGE ENGLISH DICTIONARY](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/internship) (IN A COMPANY) **a period of time** during which someone works for a company or organization in order to get experience of a particular type of work:
>
> **position** noun. [Business English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/position)  HR, WORKPLACE a job, especially one that is important:
>
> **advertise/fill a position**
>
> We hope to fill the position within the next two months.
>
> **apply for/take up/fill a position**
>
> She will soon take up an important position with a firm of lawyers.